# Laravel 5 composer wont update class not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

Whenever I do `composer update` or `artisan cache:clear` and I get the following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
Fatal error: Class 'Aws\Laravel\AwsServiceProvider' not found
```

My app.php config file doesn't contain the AWS in the providers and or aliases. I've tried adding `'Aws\Laravel\AwsServiceProvider::class,'` under providers and `'AWS => Aws\Laravel\AwsFacade::class,'` under aliases but still the same issue. I think something is caching weird and doesn't recognize the updates I'm doing on app.php config file.

Comment: Have you created AwServiceProvider previously and delete it?

Comment: Have you tried running `composer dump-autoload`? Then try running `composer update` again after.

Answer (score 3):

- delete the files (not the directory) in `bootstrap/cache`
- run `composer dump-autoload`
- remove `config/aws.php` if it exists
- run `composer install`

Comment: bootstrap cache seemed to have to offending entry for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

just do a : `composer dump-autoload`
and after that try to run you command like normal: `composer update`